# Have I created a memory leak in this function?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free

Trying to improve my C skills. This program should take a string and strip it of whitespace.

I'm aware I've made two calls to `malloc` but have only called `free` once. Have I thus got some unfreed memory somewhere, or because I assign the original pointer to the new memory, does it all vanish in the one `free` call I do make?

Thanks!

```
static void foo() {
    char *string_to_change = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    strcpy(string_to_change, "my test");
    printf("Before: %s\n", string_to_change); // "my test"
    strip_whitespace(&string_to_change);    
    printf("After: %s\n", string_to_change); // "mytest"
    free(string_to_change);
}

static void strip_whitespace(char **ptr) {
    
    char *res = malloc(strlen(*ptr));
    if (res == NULL)
        exit_with_error(NULL_POINTER);
    int current_pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*ptr); i++) {
        if (((*ptr)[i] == ' ') || ((*ptr)[i] == '\n' && ((*ptr)[i-1] == '\n' || (*ptr)[i+1] == '\0'))) {
            continue;
        }
        res[current_pos] = (*ptr)[i];
        current_pos++; 
    }
    res[current_pos] = '\0';
    *ptr = res;
}
```

Comment: Yes there's a leak, as you don't `free` the original memory allocated in `foo`.

Comment: yes, the original `string_to_change` is lost. And your `res` is 1 element too short in the worst case (no whitespace).

Comment: Each pointer returned by `malloc` (and similar functions) needs to be freed at some point by a call to `free`, otherwise you create a memory leak. No magic whatsoever is done by those functions.

Comment: Specifically `malloc(strlen(*ptr));` is wrong.

Comment: @Lundin It's right, since the function argument is `char **ptr`.

Comment: @Barmar Strings are null terminated in C. This is one of the most common C FAQ we get on this site.

Comment: So at what point should I make the other call to `free`? Before `*ptr = res;`?

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, I thought you were pointing out the `*ptr` was wrong. mch already mentioned that he didn't add 1 for the null terminator.

Comment: you can avoid reallocation of the memory in `strip_whitespace`, just update the passed array inplace with changed logic.

Comment: @HenryCooper `free(*ptr);` before `*ptr = res;`

Comment: Swapping pointers to the provided strings is never a good idea in C. You should either accept pointers to both strings - source and target - or, you can dynamically create a new string and return a pointer to it. The former is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a leak here:

```
*ptr = res;
```

Prior to this line, `*ptr` points to an allocated block of memory.  You then assign to it the starting address of another allocated block, meaning the original pointer is lost.  You should `free` right before this line:

```
free(*ptr);
*ptr = res;
```

Also, this allocation is potentially too little:

```
char *res = malloc(strlen(*ptr));
```

If `*ptr` contains no spaces to strip, `res` won't have enough memory to hold the terminating null byte.  You'll need to add 1 to this.

```
char *res = malloc(strlen(*ptr) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) means we should write code as simple as possible, not as complex as possible. That is:

- Don't mix up allocation and algorithm in a single unholy mess. Use caller allocation if possible.
- Don't use dynamic allocation unless there's an obvious need for it.
- It's usually a good idea to regard strings as "immutable" and not make in-place modifications to them unless there's specific requirements for that.
- Avoid pointer-to-pointer and weird arithmetic on pointer-to-pointers.
- The presence of `continue` in C programs is almost a dead certain indication of a needlessly complex loop.
- Don't re-invent the wheel. There's `ctype.h`.

If we are to implement this with caller allocation, the code boils down to something compact and easy to read like:

```
void strip_spaces (char* dst, const char* src)
{
  while(*src != '\0')
  {
    if(!isspace(*src))
    {
      *dst = *src;
      dst++;
    }
    src++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
}
```

Complete program:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void strip_spaces (char* dst, const char* src)
{
  while(*src != '\0')
  {
    if(!isspace(*src)) // if not string
    {
      *dst = *src; // then copy
      dst++;
    }
    src++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
}

int main (void)
{
  char str[] = "   weird  \n\r string contain    ing    spac\tes\n";
  char stripped[128];
  
  strip_spaces(stripped, str);
  puts(stripped);
}
```

Comment: While I agree with your comments in general, I think "continue" can be the simplest and clearest way to write some things. For example, iterating through a large collection of things with a few exceptions: for (...) { if (exception) continue; ... }

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Give me any loop with continue and I'm fairly confident that I can write it in more readable ways. Anyway, that's a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a memory leak inside your code.

Let's say your first call to `malloc` allocate memory at address *0x0010* and your second call allocate memory at address *0x0100*. Your *free* call will effectively free the memory at address `string_to_change` which is *0x0100* but nothing tells the compiler to free the memory at *0x0010*.

Usually, you really have to have as many `free` calls as `malloc` calls.